# Two block commands in \newenvironment

Tags: listings, environments, verbatim

What is wrong with following document?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newenvironment{code}
 {\begin{latin}\begin{verbatim}}
 {\end{verbatim}\end{latin}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{code}
hello world!
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> untitled-4.tex
```

I also tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\newenvironment{code}
 {\begin{latin}\begin{lstlisting}}
 {\end{lstlisting}\end{latin}}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
hello world!
This is a code
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

But the output is not what I expect.

Answer (score 6):

Verbatim environments are very special, and generally resist being the arguments of macros, which is effectively what you are doing when you try to put a `verbatim` environment inside another environment definition.   For more details on this problem, see the [TeX FAQ entry](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin) on the topic.

Instead, what you can do is hook into the beginning of the `verbatim` or `lstlisting` environments to switch into LTR mode.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\AtBeginEnvironment{verbatim}{\setLTR\latinfont}
\AtBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\setLTR\latinfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
hello world!
\end{verbatim}
\begin{lstlisting}
hello world!
\end{lstlisting}
این فقط یک آزمایش است
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks, What about other similar packages? I need to define a new environment?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Why do you need to define a new environment?

Comment: I want create a simple command to insert styled code embedded in a figure

Comment: And you won't be able to do it.  But with the modified environment, your LTR and font issue can easily be solved.  I've updated my answer to reflect your edits.

Comment: `listings`' `\lstnewenvironment` might help...